# How this char copy works: *(*((char**)p))++ = ch; in c

Tags: c, pointers, char, copy, embedded

I have a problem with this code I am using in embedded C. It works perfect if I pass p as a parameter of some function but not works in case of "p" is local. Please help to understand in details how this code works.

Comment: Please post a snippet with the code. Explain what you expect from it, and what happens instead.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer p is cast to char** and dereferenced twice, ch is copied to that location, and `*p` is then incremented (points to the next character.

I imagine (because without code that is all I can do) that not working "in case of `p` is local" has little to do with `p` being local and everything to do with the value of p and the contextual semantics of the code in question.  Whether the code works or not depends solely on `p` holding a valid value such that the double de-reference resolves to the intended location.

To be honest however, you should avoid writing such code, it's too "clever", and as [Brian Kernighan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan) said:

> Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?

Answer (score 0):

P is pointer  to char pointer.Initially it is typecast to `char**` and dereferencing two times.After dereferencing 2times,at this place `ch` is copied.After that it is incremented by1.Here, to understand about incrementing such a pointer, try to understand follows.`*p++`is equal to `*p` and `p++`,NOT an equal to `*p` and `(*p)++`. Like this, your pointer is also incremented. There is chance to get segmentation fault in your copy statement.